# Change calendar style on button click

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I need to change the `Calendar` `style` when clicking a `Button`. Currently, in the code below, the `style` change only works when the object is created for the first time but I need to do style change manually whenever the `Button` is clicked.

Below is the QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Private 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 400
    minimumWidth: 400
    minimumHeight: 300
    color: "#f4f4f4"
    id: root

    Calendar {
        id: cal_panel
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenter:  parent.horizontalCenter;
        frameVisible:false

        style: CalendarStyle {
            gridVisible: false
            dayDelegate: Rectangle {

                color: styleData.selected ? "#FF2E7BD2" : (styleData.visibleMonth && styleData.valid ? "#191919" : "#191919");

                Text {
                    id:day_txt
                    text: styleData.date.getDate()
                    font.bold: true
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    color: {
                        var color = "#dddddd";
                        if (styleData.valid) {
                            color = styleData.visibleMonth ?  "#bbb" : "#444";

                            var sel = root.getHiglightDates();
                            for(var i=0;i<sel.length;i++){
                                if(sel[i]===Qt.formatDateTime(styleData.date,"dd:MM:yyyy"))
                                    color="red"
                            }

                            if (styleData.selected) {
                                color = "black";
                            }
                        }
                        color;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Button{
        anchors.top:cal_panel.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        text:"Higlight"
        onClicked: {
            console.log("Higlight here....")
        }
    }  

    function getHighlightDates(){
        var sel = ["10:11:2015","12:11:2015","11:11:2015","08:11:2015","09:11:2015"];
        return sel;
    }   
}
```

**Edit:**

The return value of the function `getHighlightDates()` changes each time. In the snippet above I've just returned a predefined array for testing.  In that case I am conduced how to edit style element which is already created.

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple solution, you can reassign the style on `click` event, forcing an under the hood refresh of the `Calendar` item.

To do that you can use

```
cal_panel.style=cal_panel.style
```

Be aware that this solution is not exactly performance friendly. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments in the question and in @folibis's answer, it looks the question might just revolve around how to get the calendar style to reflect the updated list of selected dates (from `getHiglightDates()`) after a user has updated the list by clicking a button.

What about just adding a new property `selectedDates` to store the selected dates (previously held in `getHighlightDates()`) like in the code below.  By making use of property binding, the appearance of selected dates will automatically be updated whenever `selectedDates` changes. In the code below, the color of the "day_txt" `Text` is updated when `selectedData` is updated (which in turn is updated when `selectedDates` is updated).

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 400
    minimumWidth: 400
    minimumHeight: 300
    color: "#f4f4f4"
    id: root

    property variant selectedDates : ["10:11:2015","12:11:2015","11:11:2015","08:11:2015","09:11:2015"]

    Calendar {
      id: cal_panel
      anchors.topMargin: 10
      anchors.horizontalCenter:  parent.horizontalCenter;
      frameVisible:false


      style: CalendarStyle {
          gridVisible: false
          dayDelegate: Rectangle {
              property bool selectedDate: selectedDates.indexOf(Qt.formatDateTime(styleData.date,"dd:MM:yyyy")) > -1

              color: styleData.selected ? "#FF2E7BD2" : (styleData.visibleMonth && styleData.valid ? "#191919" : "#191919");

              Text {
                  id:day_txt
                  text: styleData.date.getDate()
                  font.bold: true
                  anchors.centerIn: parent
                  color: selectedDate ? "red" : (styleData.selected ? "black" : (styleData.visibleMonth ?  "#bbb" : "#444"));
              }
          }
      }
  }

    Button{
        anchors.top:cal_panel.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        text:"Higlight"
        onClicked: {
            var updatedDates = selectedDates
            updatedDates.push(Qt.formatDateTime(cal_panel.selectedDate,"dd:MM:yyyy"))
            selectedDates = updatedDates
            # See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19583234/qml-binding-to-an-array-element for why its done this way...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as @skypjack already suggested, you just can assign a new style on click. The `style` property is a `Component` so there is no problem to do something like this:

```js
Component {
    id: style1
    CalendarStyle {
        background: Rectangle { color: "lightyellow" }
    }
}
Component {
    id: style2
    CalendarStyle {
        background: Rectangle { color: "orange" }
    }
}

Calendar {
    id: calendar
    anchors.fill: parent
    style: style1
    onClicked: {
        calendar.style = style2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know this method, but what in my case on each time I click button I have to highlight different date which is returned by `getHiglightDates()` function. So my question is how can change the text color of `dayDelegate` depending on the date list returned by  `getHiglightDates()`.

Comment: @folibis The question was not clear and I've misunderstood it, your response is wrong indeed, or better, it doesn't reply to the right question. :-)